# @ExceptionHandler doesn't handle the thrown exceptions

Tags: java, spring, jsp, exception, spring-mvc

I have a method in my controller which will handle the exceptions thrown by the application. So I have a method like this one.

```
@Controller
public class ExceptionController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/error")
    @ExceptionHandler(value={Exception.class, NullPointerException.class})
    public String showError(Exception e, Model model){
        return "tiles:error";
    }
}
```

And to try I if it works I throw a NullPointerException in another method in other method controller:

```
boolean a = true;
if(a){ 
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

After the exception is thrown it is printed in the JSP, but it doesn't go throw my showError() method (I've set a breakpoint there and it never enters). showError() method will catch the exception and will show different error pages depending on the exception type (though now it always shows the same error page). If I go to the url /error it shows the error page so the showError() method is OK.

I'm using Spring 3.

What can be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to decouple exception handling from the controllers, then use a `HandlerExceptionResolver` instead: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#d0e29470

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at your logs, you'll probably see this:

> `java.lang.IllegalStateException`:
>   Unsupported argument
>   [`org.springframework.ui.Model`] for
>   `@ExceptionHandler` method

In other words, `@ExceptionHandler` methods are not permitted to declare a `Model` parameter (see [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html)).

Remove that parameter (which you're not using anyway), and it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks it's true, but it doen't solve the problem. I've realized that the exception is only caught when it is thrown by a method which is inside the same controller. It may be because of this bug: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5959

Comment: @Javi: That's not a bug, it's by design, and stated in the docs: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler

Comment: i looked at the doc page u linked to above, but I must be dense, I'm not seeing anything that says that you can't include a Model parameter in the method, can you point that out?

Comment: @chrismarx: The page lists the sort of objects you can get as parameters to the method, and the sort of objects you can return from it. `Model` is in the latter, but not the former.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to handle exceptions globally (outside your controller), then you can use a @ControllerAdvice annotated class in which you put your @ExceptionHandler annotated methods.

see http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc for an example.
And http://blog.codeleak.pl/2013/11/controlleradvice-improvements-in-spring.html for the improvements being made in spring 4.